# Trying to make text float, before a wrecking ball wrecks it

Tags: objects, rigid-body-simulation, text-object

I'm trying to create a text that is in the centre of the screen. A wrecking ball comes behind it and flings the letters everywhere. I have made the wrecking ball. I have made the text and made the text so that the wrecking ball collides and destroys the text.

However, because the text is resting on a plane I can't get the wrecking ball to be the centre of the screen. It has also forced me to rigid body constraint the letters with one another, in order to prevent letters such as "P" falling over before even being hit.

Is it possible to allow each of the letters to "fly" so that firstly, they don't need a plane to balance on and secondly so the wrecking ball can be bigger and more central to the camera?

I could render the animation and post it so you can see exactly what I mean, if I haven't been clear enough already (as I'm not great with words :P)

I'm currently using render cycles (I think that's what I'm meant to be using).

Thanks in advance to any help.

Comment: I may have solved this problem, though this feels a really cheap way of doing this. I have simply changed the collision groups. So that the plane is different from the wrecking ball. But the text is in the same group as both of them.

It seems to work so far.

Comment: please write an answer to your own question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the following workflow for achieving the desired results:

- Choose *enable deactivation* then **start deactivated** for your text objects. Also, ensure they are set to *dynamic* in your rigid body settings.[image]
- For your "wrecking ball", it needs to be set to **animated** as well as dynamic. Also, increase the *mass* of this object sufficiently.

[image]

- Now, at frame one, keyframe the starting point for your wrecking ball
  object, then move along the timeline to your end point, and set a
  *location* keyframe for your wrecking ball again.

Because *start deactivated* is enabled on your text objects, the rigid body collision does not take effect until an active object collides with it. After following these steps, you should be able to come up with something like this.

[image]

Also note that by changing the *shape* of your text objects collision you can find some interesting results. For my example, I ultimately chose to use *box* for my text instead of the default convex hull.

Comment: That is an amazingly detailed answer, thank you so much. I will try this immediately.

You even made a little gif to go with it.

Amazing, thank you.

Edit: Worked beautifully! Also allowed me to use your information to change a few things and make it all round more appealing. Thank you again :)